# Sonarqube DB Queries - How to find new issues?

Tags: sql, database, sonarqube

I need to find all the issues discovered in a snapshot/scan in Sonarqube. I can't use the web API since the volume can be excessive for new projects on first scan. I have a query that can find the latest snapshot with the project information. I can query issues by project. I can't figure out how to relate issues to a snapshot. There has to be a way since Sonarqube does it - New issues on the Project page.

Has anyone done this or have enough experience with the crazy schema to be able to figure it out? Can't wait for the schema rationalization...

Sonarqube 5.6.3 on Windows 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: The good news is that the only API to extract data is web API. So no need to understand the schema!

Comment: More seriously the webapp is a JS application. If it displays what you need then you can find the related HTTP request by profiling the network in the browser.

Comment: Try exporting 200K issues via the Web API 500 at a time...

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no association between snapshot and issue. Nor has there ever been one. The closest you can come is to use date parameters to narrow the set of issues created right around the time of your analysis. Note that this could be difficult if you run analyses close together.

The "new issues" metrics shown on the project homepage are just that - metrics. However, if you click through on one, you'll find yourself in a date-based Issues search.

You can do the same sort of thing using the web service, again, via date-based criteria. Or you could use the `sinceLeakPeriod` parameter.

Comment: And this is my problem. If I go to the Project page I can get new issues since the start of the leak period. How can I replicate that outside Sonarqube? You're significantly limiting reporting by removing dashboard customization. We need to export data to BI and recreate many of the metrics. We need to be able to make these associations.

Comment: @RichardSchaefer issues since the start of the leak period is a different question.

Comment: OK. Then let me ask that question. How do I get issues since the start of the leak period?

Comment: @RichardSchaefer [api/issues/search](https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/issues/search) has a _sinceLeakPeriod_ parameter.

Comment: @Nicolas-SonarSourceTeam - So I'd have to issue the API call for each project? I have hundreds. That's why I'm trying to replicate this in a database call...